# Error: Program type already present: org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm

Tags: android, android-studio

When I'm compiling my App (see the code below) I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Program type already present: org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm

How can I fix this?

I'm using android studio 3.0

**build.gradle app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bexride.conductor.driver"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support- annotations'
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation project(':android-switch-backport')
implementation project(':Volley')
implementation project(':library_pinnlistivew')
implementation project(':CropLibrary')
implementation project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
implementation project(':google-play-services_lib')
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
//    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
//    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile files('libs/android-query.0.26.7.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/design-25.3.0-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/simple.facebook-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.0.8.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

**build.gradle project**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow generally works in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/); please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating it ; if you wish to post in spanish you can try [Spanish version of stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please always post at SO in English. I've edited your question this time, but be sure not to do this again (usually you'll get downvotes instead of answers otherwise)

Comment: most likely `httpmime-4.3.5.jar` is already included in the other http libs.

Answer (score 0):

- in build.gradle app
- please change
- all Compile Command to implementation Command
- and rebuild your project
- i hope this will be helpful

Example::

```
   Compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

To::

```
   Implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```